# calculate the maximum and minimum number of days between each person's travels

Tags: mysql

People travel in pairs. How to find the maximum and minimum number of days between trips every user?

People:

| id | user |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Harry |
| 2 | George |
| 3 | Thomas |
| 4 | Jacob |
| 5 | Jack |
| 6 | Oliver |

Travels:

| id | date | user1 | user2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2005-10-03 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2005-10-04 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 2005-10-05 | 5 | 6 |
| 4 | 2005-10-06 | 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 2005-10-07 | 2 | 4 |
| 6 | 2005-10-08 | 3 | 5 |
| 7 | 2005-10-10 | 1 | 4 |
| 8 | 2005-10-11 | 5 | 2 |
| 9 | 2005-10-15 | 6 | 4 |

I tried to solve this problem in the following way, but I still do not understand how to solve this problem:

```
select People.id,People.user, count(*)
from People
INNER join
(SELECT MIN(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, t1.date, t2.date)) as mintime,max(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, t1.date, t2.date))
from Travels as t1
join Travels as t2 on t1.PERSON_1 = t2.PERSON_1 
WHERE t1.date< t2.date
GROUP BY t1.PERSON_1) as t3
group by People.id
```

There is an idea to use the position function to iterate over each user, and then, as a result, look at the dates and find the minimum and maximum, but I still don't understand how to do this

Comment: Show desired output for shown data.

Comment: PS. Convert to `(date-user)`, use UNION ALL.

Comment: Please post your query?  Is this an assignment?  Are you looking for someone to complete it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Best is to do it in steps with subqueries, as below (comments are in the query):

```
select user, max(dateDiff)
from (
    select
        user,
        -- get the diff between previous and current row date to get diff between trips
        datediff(date, lag(date) over (partition by user order by date)) dateDiff
    from (
        -- full flat list of all users and trip dates
        select date, user1 `user`
        from testtbl
        union all 
        select date, user2
        from testtbl
    ) a
) a group by user
```

[SQL fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jWAXDx7Np54Px2vGPh3KTC/0)

Note that I used windowed function which are not avaiable in MySql 5 and below.